# SQL ISNULL function on column in spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

I am new to spark. I am trying apply `ISNULL` function on particular column of amount.
But it is giving error as not found. Is there way to apply `ISNULL` on particular while doing any kind of aggregation.

```
val totalAmountvalueDF = sourceDF.groupBy("Id").**agg(sum(ISNULL("amount",0))**.as("totalAmountvalue"))
```

I can't apply when others on this amount column because I have some other purpose. So I have to apply `ISNULL` only while doing aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can filter the values at aggregation time. However, you definitely can filter the sum column after performing the aggregation.
Moreover, in this case, I believe you can filter the null values from the "Amount" column even before the aggregation. Your code will be more efficient since you will shuffle less data when performing the group by.

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("UserID", StringType, true),
  StructField("Amount", IntegerType, true)
))

val inputDF = Seq(Row("U1" ,3)
  ,Row("U2" ,1)
  ,Row("U1" ,0)
  ,Row("U3" ,null)
  ,Row("U1" ,1)
)

val someDF = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(inputDF), schema)

someDF.groupBy(col("UserID"))
  .agg(sum(col("Amount")).as("sum")).filter(col("sum").isNotNull)
  .show()
```

or:

```
someDF.filter(col("Amount").isNotNull)
  .groupBy(col("UserID"))
  .agg(sum(col("Amount")).as("sum"))
  .show()
```

Hope this answer you question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It will filter the data. My doubt is here, when  we join this agrregated data set with some other data set based on user id we will loose corresponding UserId information I think

Comment: Well, if you perform an inner join after the filter that is correct. If you want to keep the users with sum = null you have two options: filter after the join (depending on how much users you have with sum = null you will lose some performance) or perform a left side join.